# Concrete5 - Running multiple C5 Servers, shared MySQL, but local disks only for DocumentRoot?

Tags: cluster-computing, concrete5

I need to know if it is possible to keep multiple C5 servers in sync, while using local disks to contain the DocumentRoot for each instance.  I cannot find any documentation on the subject of basic web clustering with C5.

Currently, we have a shared MySQL server, handling all DB services. (that we don't intend to change) We also use NFS to host the DocumentRoot repository, also being used by all of our hosts, to hold the data.

We want to break away from the NFS model, and use local drives on each web server instead.  However, I don't know if C5 will have problems with this scenario, or what pitfalls are waiting for me.

I understand I will need some kind of mechanism to trigger the data propagation across local disks.  That should be simple enough to accomplish.  However C5 and its functionality may not like my plans, therefore I am asking for help.

How do "you" set up multiple C5 hosts, containing the same web sites, and keep them all in sync?  Let me know!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [storage locations](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/using-concrete5-7/dashboard/system-and-maintenance/files/file-storage-locations/) to store your files in a common location, and you can use [database sessions](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/how-tos/developers/enable-database-based-sessions-on-5.7/) to store your sessions in the common database.

Beyond that, all you need to do is make sure that you deploy any changes to file configuration in `/application/config`. Generally teams do that by ensuring that they don't make any configuration changes on the production site and instead deploy configuration changes from their staging environment.

If configuration becomes an issue, you can swap out the existing file configuration with a database based model pretty easily.